# using a double threshold

Tags: flash, actionscript, webcam, motion-detection

im using the Threshold method of the Bitmapdata object to make some motion buttons from a camera video source.

It's working with 1 button (1 threshold on 1 rectangle, that is my button onscreen), like this:

```
//...
actualFrame.draw(oldFrame, new Matrix(), null, "difference"); 
 changedPixels = actualFrame.threshold(actualFrame,rect,pt1,">",0xFF111111,0xFF00FF00,0x00FFFFFF,false); 
    if (changedPixels > 200)  {
     //my actions
    }
//...
```

This is working, threshold returns the number of changed pixel between 2 istants, if that is > of 200 (i have to tune this), an action is commited.

The problem is that i need more than 1 button, and

```
actualFrame.draw(oldFrame, new Matrix(), null, "difference"); 
changedPixels = actualFrame.threshold(actualFrame,rect,pt1,">",0xFF111111,0xFF00FF00,0x00FFFFFF,false); 
if (changedPixels > 200)  {
       //my actions
}

changedPixels2 = actualFrame.threshold(actualFrame,rect,pt2,">",0xFF111111,0xFF00FF00,0x00FFFFFF,false); 
if (changedPixels2 > 200)  {
    //my actions
}
```

i use the same dimension for the button (the rectangle rect is the same), and a different (X,Y) position: pt2 vs pt1

But this is not working, changedPixels2 is always 0, (the threshold isnt applied to the image)

how can i correct this?

Thanks

Alessio

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that threshold changes the BitmapData when it meets the correct conditions. Have you tried creating another instance of actualFrame instead of running threshold on the same one twice?

```
actualFrame.draw(oldFrame, new Matrix(), null, "difference"); 
changedPixels = actualFrame.threshold(actualFrame,rect,pt1,">",0xFF111111,0xFF00FF00,0x00FFFFFF,false); 
if (changedPixels > 200)  {
       //my actions
}

actualFrame2.draw(oldFrame, new Matrix(), null, "difference");
changedPixels2 = actualFrame2.threshold(actualFrame2,rect,pt2,">",0xFF111111,0xFF00FF00,0x00FFFFFF,false); 
if (changedPixels2 > 200)  {
    //my actions
}
```

Comment: it's gonna be very slow with 4-5 buttons, i think i tried it (w/ 2 buttons) but it was laggy and not 100% working, i'll try later once more